# Python multithreaded execution - not scalable

Tags: python, multithreading, performance

I need to run very CPU and memory - intensive python calculation (Monte-Carlo like). I benchmarked execution on development machine, can run one core due to memory (up to 9 Gb per thread). 
I attempted to run the same via the server (32 cores, 256 GB RAM) using multiprocessing.Pool. Surprisingly, increasing number of threads increases runtime per core, quite dramatically. 8 threads instead of 4 run 3 times longer each core. Performance monitor shows 9 x 8 Gb max, far below maximum available.

Win Server 2008 R2, 256 GB RAM, Intel® Xeon® Processor E5-2665 x2
I know that
1. Time is spent on the function itself, in three CPU expensive steps
2. Of them first (random drawings and conversion to events) and last (c++ module for aggregation) are much less sensitive to the problem (time to run increases up to factor 2). Second step containing python matrix algebra inc scipy.linalg.blas.dgemm function can be 6 time more expensive when I run more cores. It does not consume most memory (step 1 does, after step 1 it is no more than 5 gb)
3. If I manually run the same pieces from different dos boxes, I have identical behaviour.

I need the calculation time scalable in order to improve the performance but cannot have it. Do I miss something? Python memory limitations? WinServer 2008 specific? Blas overloads problem?

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question?

Comment: Is easier to talk about something when there is code involved. Sintetize your problem in some runnable code snippet

Comment: Since there's so many different things going on with your problem minimal working example is a must.

Answer (score 0):

You miss information about [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). In cPython threading do not give you additional performance. It allows to run calculation when some time consuming IO operations are waiting performed in other thread.

To have performance spedup your function need to release GIL. It means that it cannot be pure python, but in Cython/C/C++ with proper configuration.

Comment: The OP said about `multiprocessing.Poll` which circumvents GIL, don't?

Comment: In title and other parts he wrote about mutithread. I f he realy use multiprocessing then I think that he uses somehow shared memory during calculation instead of copy data to local memory, and use shared only for transfer.

Comment: I use multiprocessing.Pool. Moreover, I observe identical picture when running totally independent instances one thread each (different dos boxes pythons)

Comment: dos box? Maybe this is response? Maybe it is limited to one core on your machine?

Comment: @Vladimir can you ran it out of dosbox? What is the purpose of this dosbox?